# Bring more [clarity] to these tags

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

At the time of posting, the usage of the [clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clarity) tag looks unclear because it can refer to **three (or *more*) different products**.

> Clarity can refer to three products: **CA Clarity™ PPM** is a Project and Portfolio Management tool. **VMware's Clarity** is an extensible product-based framework for building clean, crisp, and modern web apps. **Blockstack's Clarity** is a Smart Contract language used to run contracts on the Stacks 2.0 blockchain.

Based on the excerpt itself, looks like these are their official sites:

- [CA Clarity™ PPM](https://ppm.itdesign.de/en/software/clarity-ppm/) ([sample questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclarity%5D+ppm&searchOn=3))
- [VMware's Clarity](https://github.com/vmware/clarity) ([sample questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclarity%5D+vmware&searchOn=3))
- Blockstack's Clarity (not sure between [the language](https://blog.blockstack.org/introducing-clarity-the-language-for-predictable-smart-contracts/) or the [JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/blockstack/clarity-js-sdk) since combining with "blockstack" didn't return anything)
- (and possibly more products with the same name that some questions are misusing this)

Searching for existing 'clarity' tags also returned:

- [vmware-clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vmware-clarity): [Clarity Design System](https://github.com/vmware/clarity)
- [proclarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/proclarity): Microsoft ProClarity
- [ms-clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-clarity): [Microsoft Clarity](https://clarity.microsoft.com/) (no tag excerpt)
- [clarity-clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clarity-clang): [Clarity Language](https://clarity-lang.org/) (newly created, seems related to Blockstack)

Looks like 1 tag is clear for the disambiguation target: [vmware-clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vmware-clarity). I'm not sure how the rest should be disambiguated, but I think [clarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clarity) should be burninated...

Comment: Bring more `[clarity]` to these tags

Comment: First thing we can do is clean out the marketing speak from [vmware-clarity]'s tag excerpt. "[C]lean, crisp, and modern web apps" huh?

Comment: I remember researching Microsoft Clarity for SO, and I'm almost positive I wrote the current tag wiki for it. I also remember my tag wiki excerpt was rejected. Weirdly enough, both of these actions appear on this [Microsoft Clarity user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15155080/microsoft-clarity?tab=activity), not my profile.